# Cross platform framework for a beginner

Tags: cross-platform, desktop-application

I want to develop an app for DESKTOP. I have a plan to build on ANDROID and IOS too in future. I don't know which platform to use.
Recommend me cross platform frameworks through which I should build on DESKTOP(Mac and Windows PC), ANDROID and IOS.
I will build it first for PCs, then ANDROID and IOS.

Answer (score 0):

To start with, you might want to take a look at [JavaFX](https://openjfx.io/), [Electron](https://www.electronjs.org/), [QT](https://www.qt.io/) - these would work both for Desktop and IOS/Android.

If you're developing with .NET, you could also look at
[Xamarin Forms](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/apps/xamarin/xamarin-forms) and [AlterNET UI](https://alternet-ui.com) .NET frameworks - the former one can be used for creating apps that run on Desktop/IOS/Android, while latter one focusing on creating native-looking interfaces on Windows/macOS/Linux for desktops (no IOS/Andriod), and still in beta.